# How Is the Jacobian squared ( truncated Hessian) approximately equal to the Hessian

Tags: calculus, optimization, matrix-calculus, jacobian

I'm currently work on second order optimization. 
And I'm stuck at quass Newton method. 
I'm are trying to approximate the Hessian without actually computing the Hessian .
Please tell  how can the Hessian be represented using the gradient or Jacobian

Answer (score 2):

Nonlinear least squares solves a problem of the form
minimize $\frac{1}{2} \Sigma_{i=1}^m R_i(x_1,...,x_n)^2$

The Jacobian, $J$, of the objective function being minimized is the matrix whose (i,j) element = $\frac{\partial{R_i(x_1,...,x_n)}}{\partial{x_j}}$

The Hessian, $H$, of the objective function being minimized = $J^TJ + \Sigma_{i=1}^m R_i(x_1,...,x_n) * \text{Hessian}(R_i(x_1,...,x_n)).$. The 2nd term consists of "2nd order" terms, and is of small magnitude for $x$  near the optimum solution of the problem, provided the residuals, $R_i(x_1,...,x_n)$, are small in magnitude at the solution (i.e., low residual problem). Under these circumstances, the Hessian can be approximated by $J^TJ$, and it usually works fairly well, unless the residuals are too large. Such approximation to the Hessian is used in the Gauss-Newton and Levenberg-Marquardt algorithms.

Quasi-Newton algorithms build up an approximation to the Hessian (or in some cases, the Hessian inverse) of a general (twice continuously differentiable) objective function, by using the differences of gradients across several optimization algorithm iterations.  Different Quasi-Newton algorithms do this in different ways.  The Quasi-Newton Hessian approximation may perform well in its role in the optimization algorithm, but is not necessarily a close approximation to the true Hessian.